# Scale Div with content to fit viewport

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have div with elements inside it. All elements are perfectly aligned. But I need to scale this div to fir viewport. I use now css scale but it don't support pixels so I cant enter size in pixels.

[image]

I need it looks like this. This is scaled div but it scaled manualy by entering css values. So how can I scale div to fit the screen preserving all elements size.

Comment: You could probably use percentages being your parent div 100% of the viewport and the remaining ones 20% with margins around. You would make it responsive to whatever viewport you are working on

Comment: Could you show us your (minimal) code - the CSS and the relevant HTML?

Comment: there many ways to accomplish it. The question remains what you intent to do afterwards and how it should look afetrwards. Also what you wanna do with a possible overflow. CSS-Grid is one way, flex boxes another way. Just to mention the 2 methods to be your solution mostlikely. However you should also provide all necessary code you already have.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this in the head of your html document, it should help:

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you try the `vw` unit?
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp

You could give a width to you container (and other elements like the text), similar to [Font scaling based on width of container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056591/font-scaling-based-on-width-of-container)